# How can I put down stuck rear sunshade on a 2006 Mercedes E class?

Tags: electrical, mercedes-benz

I have a 2006 Mercedes E-350 with an automatic rear sunshade; until a week ago the sunshade worked fine, but now it's stuck up and I can't get it to come down by any means.

The button to move the shade doesn't respond; I can hear a click in the back of the car but that's it; none of the other mechanical noises it makes when it comes down proper. I can't physically push it back down, even after loosening the arms a bit (I got it about 20% down before it stopped moving). Even after loosening the arm's position the button doesn't work, though on occasion I've heard *slightly* more mechanical noises after pressing the button.

I've tried several tricks Mercedes forums recommend; I had someone push down on the shade while I press the button; no luck, it doesn't move. I heard the problem might be caused by a blown fuse, but I don't know which fuse it would be or how to get to the front fuse-box, actually; I can't seem to access the driver's side primary one if it's in there. I can see the rear fuse box but can't seem to open it.

At this point I don't really care if the sun shade comes back up but I want it down; I'm content to not use it again if it's not going to work. At the same time I'd rather not *break* it, at least not more than it already is, because the mechanism allegedly costs something around $1500.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer: it appears that common fuse box locations on the mercs are near the hinges of the hood in the engine compartment and under the rear seat (to the side rather than directly beneath).

Comment: Another spot would be on the extreme left of the dashboard: open the driver's side door and check for a fuse box there as well.

Comment: @BobCross that's where it's supposed to be according to the manual but I didn't see anything that could be opened, unless it needs prying. Manual says where the boxes are but not how to open them... I'll double check in better light though. I'll be talking with a mech soon (though he's an audio guy) and have him peek at the fuses if he gets to it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took her in to s Mercedes licensed mechanic, they took apart the assembly. Turns out the Up motor worked fine, but the Down motor was burt out.

It's *possible* a similar situation could be caused by something as simple as a blown fuse or a misalignment of the "scissor" bars that raise/lower the shade, but that wasn't the case here.

Since it was the dead motor and not something simple they'd have had to replace *the entire assembly* which costs $1700. They're expensive because no one bothers to replace them, most places won't have them in stock. Instead they (carefully) shoved the shade back into it's housing and took out the fuse so it couldn't be accidentally put up again. If this happens to you make sure you take the fuse for the sunshade out!

Comment: I think this is a lot of misinformation in few words. There is no up vs. down motor. The sunshade motors are widely available used (as are most parts on an '06 E350). This really doesn't fix the problem. It's just permanently breaking it. You should find a mechanic willing to take the care to find the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

People with rear shade stuck in the up position:  I have a 2004 E320 with the same issue.  I was looking through all the blogs and $1100 - $1700 US is way too much to pay for a cheap part on an expensive car.

Pull on the shade away from the window and the whole mechanism is visible.  The motor is dead center.   The shaft is pushed out, looks like a small pin sticking out.  Start the car, have some intermittently push the shade switch and with one hand on the shade pushing down and the other pushing directly on the motor shaft.  The shade starts to come down.  It may take a few pushes to get it all the way down!

If you still don’t see it I can take pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the sunshade problem (I have it too) but the passenger compartment fusebox is on the driver's side. The door has to be open and it does need to be prised off. Use a flat blunt object so you don't damage the panel.

Comment: Is it always on the Driver's side, or does that depend if it is a left- or right-hand drive car?

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2005 E500. Bought it with the sunshade not working in the up position. My mechanic checked all fuses concluded the motor was bad. Here is the easy fix. With the assistance of another person, apply gentle pressure to the scissor arms towards the center of the main cross bar. At the same time guide the main cross bar down. As the entire unit starts to collapse, it will go back inside fairly easily. Took about 45 seconds and did not cost me $1700. Just got the window tinted for $40. Hope this helps.